# Mule ESB and Log 4J2 Routing Appenders

Tags: mule, esb, log4j2

I am running tests against a Mule Application from AnyPoint Studio and using JUnit to code the tests. I need to be able to capture log data nicely and neatly into one log file per test...

I created a Routing Appender that works nicely for tests against our logging component directly (uses the log4j2 that comes with AnyPoint  5.0.1).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
    <properties>
        <property name="MULE_HOME">E:/</property>
        <property name="APP_NAME">A_MULE_APP</property>
    </properties>

    <Appenders>
        <Console name="stdout" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
        </Console>
        <RollingFile name="MyLog2"
            fileName="${MULE_HOME}/logs/applogs/LOG-${A_MULE_APP}.log"
            filePattern="${MULE_HOME}/logs/applogs/LOG-${A_MULE_APP}_%d{yyyyMMdd}.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%m%n" />
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>      
        <!-- Messages from standard java or mule logging -->
        <RollingFile name="other"
            fileName="${MULE_HOME}/logs/applogs/SYS-${A_MULE_APP}.log"
            filePattern="${MULE_HOME}/logs/applogs/SYS-${A_MULE_APP}_%d{yyyyMMdd}.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%-5p %d [%t] %c: %m%n" />
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
        <Routing name="RoutingAppender">
            <Routes pattern="$${ctx:filename}">
                <Route>
                    <File name="File"
                        fileName="${ctx:filename}"
                        filePattern="${ctx:filename}.%i.log.gz">
                        <PatternLayout pattern="%m%n" />
                        <Policies>
                            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
                        </Policies>
                    </File>
                </Route>
                <Route ref="MyLog2" key="${ctx:filename}"/>
            </Routes>
        </Routing>      
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.mylogging" level="INFO" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="stdout" />
            <AppenderRef ref="RoutingAppender" />               
        </Logger>
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="stdout" />
            <AppenderRef ref="other" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

In my test code I use

```
    ThreadContext.put("ctx", "filename");
```

If I call the logger from my test code

```
    logger.info("this is some info");
```

Then the right information is sent into the correct file.. Bu what I need is our logging component writing this information to the file ..

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: Sounds like your solution worked.   Are you saying that you don't want to have tests doing any Log configuration (like the ThreadContext property)?

Comment: Hi! and thanks for the response, yes.. from AnyPoint Studio it did work as long as the MULE app wasn't spun up. Once that occurred, the ThreadContext was not valid for the app that was running... I did have a solution though...

Comment: I created two additional properties in the log4j2 xml, called logfile and logfiledirectory, I then load up the xml into a DOM - replacing those values with what I want them to be and then reload the log4j2.xml Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

---

Is there a reason that you specifically need to capture the test logs in files?

Would an in-memory String not suffice?  You can create a custom Appender for your logger in each individual test, that writes to a StringBuffer, then run asserts against the resulting string.

You'll need to create your own custom Appender.  [You can see how to do that here](http://andrew-flower.com/blog/Create_Custom_Log4j_Plugins#A+String+Appender).  After that you could write tests like:

```
public void testBlaBla () {
   StringAppender a = createAppenderForTest("com.some.package.Class");
   objectToTest.methodThatDoesLogging();
   assertEquals(EXPECTED_LOG_LINE, a.getOutput());
}
public void createAppenderForTest(String loggerName) {
   StringAppender appender = StringAppender.createStringAppender(PATTERN);
   appender.addToLogger(loggerName, Level.INFO);
   appender.start();
}
```